Find an equivalence relation $T$ on $X$ such that $(X/R)/S$ is one-to-one with $X/T$ under $[[x]_R]_S\mapsto[x]_T$?
I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I tried the following:
When we define the equivalence relation $R$, we will have $X/R$ with the following classes:
$$[r]=\{x:x\in X \wedge x\stackrel{R}{\equiv}r\}$$
When we define the equivalence relation $S$, we will have $(X/R)/S$ with the following classes:
$$[[r]]= \{[x]: [x]\in (X/R) \wedge [x]\stackrel{S}{\equiv}[r]  \}$$
If we define the classes in $X/T$ as:
$$[t]=\{x: x\in X \wedge x \in \cup[[t]]\}$$
And hence, when we compute $[[r]_R]_S$ we get:
$$[[r]_R]_S=\{[r],[s],\dots\}=\{\{r,r_1,\dots\},\{s,s_1,\dots\},\dots \}$$
And when we compute $[r]_T$, we get:
$$[r]_T=\bigcup \{\{r,r_1,\dots\},\{s,s_1,\dots\},\dots \}=\{r,r_1,\dots,s,s_1,\dots \}$$
Suppose the mapping $[[x]_R]_S\mapsto[x]_T$ is not one-to-one: Then there exists $y\in X/T$ such that the preimage of $y$ has at least two different elements $\alpha=\{[r],[s],\dots\},\beta=\{[r],[s],\dots,[t],\dots\}$ with $[t]\not\in U$. But $[r],[s],[t],\dots$ are non-empty disjoint subsets of $X$ and if $\cup \alpha =\cup \beta=y$, then $[t]$ is empty, contradiction.
Is it correct?

That might turn out to be ok, but I find it rather confusing. Why don't you just define $xTy$ iff $[x]_R S [y]_R$? It follows immediately that the above correspondence is one-to-one.

@amrsa Yeah, that would also work! I guess I understood well what's "under the hood" in this problem but I struggled to write it in a decent way and got really confused a bunch of times.
